# play sound of youtube video when app is in background

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api

I am using `RMYouTubeExtractor` to play youtube video inside my app in a `MPMoviePlayerController`.

I need to play the sound of the video (and show the thumbnail of the video on the lock screen) if the phone is locked or the app is in the background.

Is there any way to do that ?

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: apple didnt provide the API to communicate with the lock screen.So it is not possible yet

Comment: you can try via notifications

Comment: i am pretty sure it is possible but i don't know how to do it @Mr.T several apps did this

Comment: what do you mean via notifications ? how ? @Mr.T

Comment: can you please mention some of the apps here. I would love to have a look at them.

Comment: all the music downloaders apps (musify for example or soundcloud) .. again i need the sound not the video to play in background @Mr.T